# Authenticating against active directory using python + ldap

Tags: python, authentication, active-directory, ldap

How do I authenticate against AD using Python + LDAP. I'm currently using the python-ldap library and all it is producing is tears.

I can't even bind to perform a simple query:

```
import sys
import ldap


Server = "ldap://my-ldap-server"
DN, Secret, un = sys.argv[1:4]

Base = "dc=mydomain,dc=co,dc=uk"
Scope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName="+un+"))"
Attrs = ["displayName"]

l = ldap.initialize(Server)
l.protocol_version = 3
print l.simple_bind_s(DN, Secret)

r = l.search(Base, Scope, Filter, Attrs)
Type,user = l.result(r,60)
Name,Attrs = user[0]
if hasattr(Attrs, 'has_key') and Attrs.has_key('displayName'):
  displayName = Attrs['displayName'][0]
  print displayName

sys.exit()
```

Running this with `myusername@mydomain.co.uk password username` gives me one of two errors:

`Invalid Credentials` - When I mistype or intentionally use wrong credentials it fails to authenticate.

> ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS: {'info': '80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, vece', 'desc': 'Invalid credentials'}

Or

> ldap.OPERATIONS_ERROR: {'info': '00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C090627, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, vece', 'desc': 'Operations error'}

What am I missing out to bind properly?

I am getting the same errors on fedora and windows.

Comment: "...and all it is producing is tears."   Does **tears** rhyme with Bears or Beers?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I was missing

```
l.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
```

From the init.

Comment: The root cause of this bug is that you have referrals in the initial response and the windows LDAP code does not send the credentials to the referral server. If you used kerberos credentials it should work.

Comment: I had different symptoms but this same option fixed my problem. Summarized it in a blog post: http://www.chaverma.com/blog/index.php/2013/06/python-ldap-functions-run-forever-against-activedirectory/

Comment: Not sure if related, but I had the same problem and it seems 1729's solution did something - But sometimes the LDAP server just answers INVALID CREDENTIALS immediately. After a while it calms down and works again.

Answer (score 34):

If you are open to using pywin32, you can use Win32 calls from Python. This is what we do in our CherryPy web server:

```
import win32security
token = win32security.LogonUser(
    username,
    domain,
    password,
    win32security.LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK,
    win32security.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT)
authenticated = bool(token)
```

Comment: This solution worked for me in a Python Flask application while behind a restrictive NTLM corporate proxy. Some other LDAP-based options simply wouldn't work.

Comment: @Gigaflop I had similar issues, after debugging for 4 hours I finally found this thread

Answer (score 7):

That worked for me, **l.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)** was the key to access the ActiveDirectory. Moreover, I think that you should add an "con.unbind()" in order to close the connection before finishing the script.

Comment: From the [python-ldap documentation](http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap.html): Instances of `LDAPObject` are returned by `initialize()`. The connection is automatically unbound and closed when the LDAP object is deleted.

Comment: You close the session, not the connection.

Answer (score 6):

Here's some simple code that works for me.

```
import ldap  # run 'pip install python-ldap' to install ldap module.
conn = ldap.open("ldaphost.company.com")
conn.simple_bind_s("myuser@company.com", "mypassword")
```

This is based on a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10743770/487992).

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, you'll receive `AttributeError: module 'ldap' has no attribute 'open'`

Answer (score 4):

Based on the excellent [ldap3 tutorial](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html):

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, NTLM
server = Server('server_name_or_ip', get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, user="user_name", password="password", auto_bind=True)
conn.extend.standard.who_am_i()
server.info
```

I did the above in Python3 but it's supposed to be compatible with Python 2.

Answer (score 3):

if you have Kerberos installed and talking to AD, as would be the case with, say, Centrify Express installed and running, you might just use python-kerberos. E.g.

```
import kerberos
kerberos.checkPassword('joe','pizza','krbtgt/x.pizza.com','X.PIZZA.COM')`
```

would return True a user 'joe' has password 'pizza' in the Kerberos realm X.PIZZA.COM.
(typically, I think, the latter would be the same as the name of the AD Domain)

Answer (score 2):

I see your comment to @Johan Buret about the DN not fixing your problem, but I also believe that is what you should look into.

Given your example, the DN for the default administrator account in AD will be:
cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=co,dc=uk - please try that.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to add

> l.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)

but instead of an error Python just hangs and won't respond to anything any more. Maybe I'm building the search query wrong, what is the Base part of the search? I'm using the same as the DN for the simple bind (oh, and I had to do `l.simple_bind`, instead of `l.simple_bind_s`):

```
import ldap
local = ldap.initialize("ldap://127.0.0.1")
local.simple_bind("CN=staff,DC=mydomain,DC=com")
#my pc is not actually connected to this domain 
result_id = local.search("CN=staff,DC=mydomain,DC=com", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "cn=foobar", None)
local.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
result_type, result_data = local.result(result_id, 0)
```

I'm using AD LDS and the instance is registered for the current account.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but it was regarding the password encoding

```
.encode('iso-8859-1')
```

Solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Distinguished Name to log on your system.`"CN=Your user,CN=Users,DC=b2t,DC=local"`
It should work on any LDAP system, including AD

Answer (score 0):

For me changing from `simple_bind_s()` to `bind()` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing LDAP with python is easier with ldap3. I have used it couple of times and seems pretty easier and secure. Official documentation is easier to understand and follow.
https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/