# Authenticating to Active Directory with python-ldap always returns (97, [])

Tags: python, authentication, active-directory, python-ldap

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140439/authenticating-against-active-directory-using-python-ldap), I am trying to perform simple authentication to a 2003 Active Directory using python ldap (CentOS 6.2 x86_64, Python 2.6.6, python-ldap 2.3.10).

Despite following all the usual steps in the init, including

```
conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
```

if I pass the correct credentials I *always* get a `(97, [])` returned:

```
>>> import ldap
>>> conn = ldap.initialize('ldap://ad.server.domain.com')
>>> conn.protocol_version = 3
>>> conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
>>> conn.simple_bind_s('user@domain.com', 'WrongPassword')
ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS: {'info': '80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, vece', 'desc': 'Invalid credentials'}
>>> conn.simple_bind_s('user@domain.com', 'CorrectPassword')
(97, [])
```

Error code 97 is not a success; it's the `LDAP_REFERRAL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED` error being returned from AD.  Nor can I use it as a *de facto* success indicator, because:

```
>>> conn.simple_bind_s('', 'CorrectPassword')
(97, [])
>>> conn.simple_bind_s('', '')
(97, [])
```

Even more frustrating is that this script is a migration from an old Perl script using Net::LDAP, which *does* return 0 for a successful authenticated bind to the same AD and server.

All the information I can find on python-ldap indicates that what I am doing should Just Work; I would be inclined to think there's something wrong with the AD servers, but the Perl script does return the correct LDAP code on a successful bind.

I have tested python-ldap 2.2.0 and python 2.4.4 on an old CentOS 5.5 box I had lying around and it "fails" in exactly the same way.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

EDIT: Per request, here is the Perl script that works.  `Net::LDAP` returns the return code from the LDAP server, and the AD server is returning 0x00, "Successful request", AFAICT.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Net::LDAP;

## Corporate subdomains
my @domains = ("americas", "asia", "europe");

# AD connect timeout
my $timeout = 10;
# Set AD server info.
my $port = "389";
my $host = "server.domain.com";

my $user = shift @ARGV;
chomp $user;

my $password = <STDIN>;
$password =~ s/\r\n//;
chomp $password;

my $ldap = Net::LDAP->new($host, port => $port, timeout => $timeout ) ||
        die "Unable to connect to LDAP server";

my $bind_return = 1;
foreach (@domains) {
        my $result = $ldap->bind( "$user\@$_.domain.com", password => $password );
        if( $result->code == 0) {
                $bind_return = 0;
                last;
        }
}

## Unbind and return
$ldap->unbind;

if ($bind_return) { print "Authentication Failed.  Access Denied\n" }
exit $bind_return;
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant Perl code?

Comment: I assume that for server.domain.com you meant ad.server.domain.com to match the python?  Also, the default port is 389 but it might be good to add ":389" to the URL explicitly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Michael Ströder, the author of the python-ldap library, enlightened me thus:

> The 97 is not the LDAP result code. It's the result type
>   ldap.RES_BIND. Normally you don't have to look at the results returned
>   by LDAPObject.simple_bind_s() (unless you want to extract the bind
>   response controls).
>
> If the LDAP result code is not 0 the accompanying exception is raised
>   like ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS in your example.
>
> So your code should look like this:

```
try:
  conn.simple_bind_s('user@domain.com', 'WrongPassword')
except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
  user_error_msg('wrong password provided')
```

The reason for these results:

```
>>> conn.simple_bind_s('', 'CorrectPassword')
(97, [])
>>> conn.simple_bind_s('', '')
(97, [])
```

is that out of the box 2003 Active Directory [allows anonymous binds](http://www.petri.co.il/anonymous_ldap_operations_in_windows_2003_ad.htm).  So not providing a user id at all will still pass a simple bind check, if the only thing being tested is whether `simple_bind_s()` throws an error.

2003 Active Directory *does* require authentication for any searches that aren't attributes of the rootDSE, so for our internal purposes we added a trivial search to the `try:` block:

```
try:
  conn.simple_bind_s('user@domain.com', 'SubmittedPassword')
  conn.search_st('DC=domain,DC=com', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '(objectClass=container)', 'name', 0, 30)
except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
  user_error_msg('wrong password provided')
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your `conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)` isn't being affected.

Therefore, try this:

```
import ldap

ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS,0)
ldap.protocol_version = 3
conn = ldap.initialize('ldap://....')
conn.simple_bind_s('user@domain.com', 'RightPassword')
```

Comment: No joy, I'm afraid.  Still returns `(97, [])`.  I did verify with conn.get_option() that these options were getting set properly for the conn SimpleLDAPObject instance.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think in the Perl script, it is using `user@europe.domain.com`?