# Copy file to file server with authentication

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am using python shutil.copy() method to copy the file to file server earlier as there is no credentials or authentication required. Now there is a change in ldap server which requires authentication to copy the file.

```
shutil.copy(file_path, target)
```

Is there anyway to copy the file to file server without mounting. I required help for my windows pc with python3.

Comment: this is like a windows shared drive? and you want to access it as `\\server\folder\filename.txt`?

Comment: I have server address like \\address , and i have to copy file to that drive.

Comment: ahh thats what i meant ... this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/141729/541038