# Accessing a directory using python and active directory username and password

Tags: python, active-directory

I want to save a file at location which is different than the working directory. Also I want to provide active directory username and password to access this location. 
     location = \itfpw4701\IT Support\test
     username = user
     password = password

How can I do this using python ? Thanks everybody for taking some time and helping me solving this issue.

Comment: active directory uses LDAP (thats a hint ;P ) (it should be very easy with that hint)

Comment: You should be able to find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140439/authenticating-against-active-directory-using-python-ldap

Comment: Thanks for the hint Joran. I did some search but unfortunately could not figure out much. I have used python more for data analysis so don't have much background about active directory or LDAP. COuld you please elaborate more if possible