# Python ldap module not throwing any exception

Tags: python, ldap

I am trying to use [LDAP python link](https://gist.github.com/ibeex/1288159) to use this function. I am simply trying to implement this as a function . Passing parameters something like this:

```
check_credentials(username="xxxxxx",password="xxx")
```

But it goes into hanged state and after 5-7 mins it completes execution with no output. Can someone suggets me some good article for this

Comment: Based on the last lines: if all goes well, the function will fill search results into `cherrypy.session` (whatever it is), closes connection and then returns None.

Comment: @Berci: Well I am passing wrong credentials. I am expecting `except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS:`

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your sample code, the LDAP_USER_NAME is a not in the expected DN (distinguished name) format. Typically, Active Directory users have a DN in the format of cn=<username>,cn=users,<domain>. For example, user bjensen in the example.com domain typically would have this DN: cn=bjensen,cn=users,dc=example,dc=com

My guess is that either Active Directory or the Python LDAP library may not return invalid credentials if the DN part is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks! Will check and get back to u :)

Comment: I followed code this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140439/authenticating-against-active-directory-using-python-ldap and it helped.