# LDAP search with username as variable

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap, python-ldap

I am using the Python-LDAP module and trying to make a query on the logged in user.  The username will be passed into the query.  When I simply type the **username in as a string my results come out correctly**.

But **if I try to pass the (username) variable it returns 
`LDAPError - FILTER_ERROR: {'desc': u'Bad search filter'}`**  I've tried a number of different combinations but continue to get the same error returned.  Any insight here would be great!

Edited for Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:

```
import ldap

LDAP_SERVER = "ldap://myldapserver.domain.ad:389"
username = r"domain\serviceAccount"
password = "Password"

l = ldap.initialize(LDAP_SERVER)
def login(username, password):
    try:
        l.simple_bind_s(username, password)
        base = "OU=Users,OU=Group,DC=domain,DC=ad"

        criteria = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=anActualUsername))" #WORKS    
        criteria = '(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s))' % username #DOESNT WORK
        criteria = "(&(objectClass=user)" + "(sAMAccountName=" + username + "))" #DOESNT WORK

        attributes = ['displayName']
        result = l.search_s(base, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, criteria, attributes)
        print result
    except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
        return False
    return True

login(username,password)
```

Comment: I suggest you `print criteria` and `print repr(criteria)` in each case.

Comment: Just added the results in my edit

Comment: @Robᵩ any other ideas?  I feel like I've tried everything.

Comment: I suggest you reduce your original program to the smallest complete program that demonstrates the problem. Copy-paste that program in its entirety into your question, editing only any sensitive information or credentials. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: Ok, cleaned up completely now with Minimal example.

Comment: Can you give an example of "anActualUserName"? More specifically, does it include the backslash character?

Comment: no backslash character, no domain.  Its simply bobsmith, or whatever the logged in username would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use ldap.filter.filter_format for proper character escaping.

```
import ldap.filter

criteria= ldap.filter.filter_format('(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s))', [username])
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to encode your string ?

```
criteria = ('(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s))' % username).encode('utf8')
```

Comment: Just tried this, no dice unfortunately. Still getting 'Bad Search Filter'

Answer (score 1):

In the "WORKS" case, your filter string contains a simple name with no domain:

```
    (&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=bobsmith))
```

In the "DOESN'T WORK" case, you use a name with a domain:

```
    (&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=domain\serviceAccount)
```

The character `\` is not allowed in a filter string unless it is escaped.

How to fix this depends upon the data present in your ldap server. Perhaps this:

```
criteria = '(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s))' % (
    username if '\\' not in username else username.split('\\')[1])
```

Or perhaps this:

```
criteria = '(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s))' % (
    ldap.filter.escape_filter_chars(username))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching single quotes with double quotes.

```
criteria = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=anActualUsername))" #WORKS    
criteria = '(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s))' % username #DOESNT WORK
```

the second criteria change it to this one (I didn't try with %s but only string):

```
criteria = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s))" % username #SHOULD WORK
```