# How to create authorization in fastapi through Windows AD?

Tags: python, fastapi

How to create authorization in fastapi through Windows AD (not Azure AD)
There is an AD server with users, it is necessary that you can log in to fastapi through this AD

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140439/authenticating-against-active-directory-using-python-ldap ? The same strategy using a `Depends` call to inject an ldap connection when necessary in your login route (i.e. together with the OAuth2Password.. class) should work?